# No GPS Exif data on iPhone XS

Tags: iphone, gps, exif

In the past, with my iPhone 6s I was able to take a picture and then, on Windows, view the gps data. Now with my new iPhone XS, the GPS information is no longer there as well as a lot of other data is missing such as the Camera Make/Model, ISO speed etc. I have checked to ensure that location is allowed for the camera app. Any ideas?

[image: iPhone XS]

[image: iPhone 6s]

Comment: How are you transferring the photos from iPhone to Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to check EXIF Data on iPhone using Third party apps like
[EXIF Viewer by Fluntro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/exif-viewer-by-fluntro/id944118456?mt=8) or any other EXIF Apps you can get for free on Appstore.

Chances are high that, EXIF informations are stripped while you transferred photo from iPhone to Windows. Normally, iPhone to Mac photo transfer over airdrop doesn't strip EXIF Metadata. But since I am not sure how you transferred photos to Windows Machine, I can't comment

Attaching screenshot with EXIF of photo took on iPhone XS Max, Apple's Camera app does record EXIF details including Camera Model, Aperture, Shutter Speed, ISO etc.

[image: EXIF app screenshot]

Disclaimer: I have developed the EXIF Viewer by Fluntro App